# Create new Taxonomy, add extra fields, register terms AND extra fields values?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, terms

I need to create a new Taxonomy (nbateam), add extra fields to this taxonomy ('code', 'color', ...) **AND** register them when the plugin initiate.

For now I'm able to do everything except register values for the extra fields I create.

code I use :

```
<?php
// Taxonomy part
add_action( 'init', 'create_nbateam_taxonomy', 0 );
// Extra fields
add_action( 'nbateam_add_form_fields', 'add_extra_fields_to_nbateam_taxonomy' );
add_action( 'create_nbateam', 'save_extra_fields_to_nbateam_taxonomy' );
add_action( 'edit_nbateam', 'save_extra_fields_to_nbateam_taxonomy' );
add_action( 'nbateam_edit_form_fields', 'edit_extra_fields_to_nbateam_taxonomy' );
// Register terms
add_action( 'init', 'register_new_terms_to_nbateam_taxonomy' );

function create_nbateam_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Nba Teams', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'nba-teams' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Nba Team', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'nba-teams' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Nba Teams', 'nba-teams' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Nba Teams', 'nba-teams' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'nba-teams' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'nba-teams' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'nba-teams' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'nba-teams' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'nba-teams' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'nba-teams' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'nba-teams' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Nba Teams with commas', 'nba-teams' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Nba Teams', 'nba-teams' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used Nba Teams', 'nba-teams' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Nba Teams', 'nba-teams' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Nba Teams', 'nba-teams' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'nba-teams' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No Nba Teams', 'nba-teams' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Nba Teams list', 'nba-teams' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Nba Teams list navigation', 'nba-teams' ),
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                       => 'nba-teams',
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
        'show_in_rest'               => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'nbateam', array( 'post' ), $args );

    // Flush rewrite rules after create new taxonomy
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

function add_extra_fields_to_nbateam_taxonomy( $taxonomy_name ) {

    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="team-code">Code</label>
        <input type="text" name="team-code" id="team-code"/>
        <p>Fill the Team Code ( ex: Hawks -> ATL ) </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="team-nba-id">Nba Id</label>
        <input type="text" name="team-nba-id" id="team-nba-id"/>
        <p>Fill the Team Nba Id for Api ( ex: Hawks -> 1610612737 ) </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="team-espn-id">Espn Id</label>
        <input type="text" name="team-espn-id" id="team-espn-id"/>
        <p>Fill the Team Espn Id for Api ( ex: Hawks -> 1 ) </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="team-color">Color</label>
        <input type="text" name="team-color" id="team-color"/>
        <p>Fill the Team Color Hex Code ( ex: Hawks -> #e21a37 ) </p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function save_extra_fields_to_nbateam_taxonomy( $term_id ) {

    //collect all term related data for this new taxonomy
    $term_item = get_term( $term_id, 'nbateam' );
    $term_slug = $term_item->slug;

    //collect our custom fields
    $term_team_code = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['team-code'] );
    $term_team_nba_id = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['team-nba-id'] );
    $term_team_espn_id = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['team-espn-id'] );
    $term_team_color = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['team-color'] );

    //save our custom fields as wp-options
    update_option( 'term_team_code_' . $term_slug, $term_team_code );
    update_option( 'term_team_nba_id_' . $term_slug, $term_team_nba_id );
    update_option( 'term_team_espn_id_' . $term_slug, $term_team_espn_id );
    update_option( 'term_team_color_' . $term_slug, $term_team_color );
}

function edit_extra_fields_to_nbateam_taxonomy( $term ) {

    //collect the term slug
    $term_slug = $term->slug;

    //collect our saved term field information
    $term_team_code = get_option( 'term_team_code_' . $term_slug );
    $term_team_nba_id = get_option( 'term_team_nba_id_' . $term_slug );
    $term_team_espn_id = get_option( 'term_team_espn_id_' . $term_slug );
    $term_team_color = get_option( 'term_team_color_' . $term_slug );

    //output our additional fields
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row">
            <label for="team-code">Code</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="team-code" id="team-code" value="<?php echo $term_team_code; ?>"/>
            <p class="description">Fill the Team Code ( ex: Hawks -> ATL ) </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row">
            <label for="team-nba-id">Nba Id</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="team-nba-id" id="team-nba-id" value="<?php echo $term_team_nba_id; ?>"/>
            <p class="description">Fill the Team Nba Id for Api ( ex: Hawks -> 1610612737 ) </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row">
            <label for="team-espn-id">Espn Id</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="team-espn-id" id="team-espn-id" value="<?php echo $term_team_espn_id; ?>"/>
            <p class="description">Fill the Team Espn Id for Api ( ex: Hawks -> 1 ) </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row">
            <label for="team-color">Color</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="team-color" id="tteam-color" value="<?php echo $term_team_color; ?>"/>
            <p class="description">Fill the Team Color Hex Code ( ex: Hawks -> #e21a37 ) </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

function register_new_terms_to_nbateam_taxonomy() {
    $this->taxonomy = 'nbateam';
    $this->terms = array (
        '0' => array (
            'name'          => 'Atlanta Hawks',
            'slug'          => 'atlanta-hawks',
            'description'   => 'Atlanta Hawks Page'
            'code'          => 'ATL',
            'nba-id'        => '1610612737',
            'espn-id'       => '1',
            'color'         => '#e21a37',
        ),
        '1' => array (
            'name'          => 'Boston Celtics',
            'slug'          => 'boston-celtics',
            'description'   => 'Boston Celtics Page'
            'code'          => 'BOS',
            'nba-id'        => '1610612738',
            'espn-id'       => '2',
            'color'         => '#00611b',
        ),
    );

    foreach ( $this->terms as $term_key=>$term) {
        // insert new terms in taxonomy
        wp_insert_term(
            $term['name'],
            $this->taxonomy,
            array(
                'slug'          => $term['slug'],
                'description'   => $term['description'],
                // Doesn't work !!
                'code'          => $term['code'],
                'nba-id'        => $term['nba-id'],
                'espn-id'       => $term['espn-id'],
                'color'         => $term['color'],
            )
        );

        unset( $term );
    }
}
```

The last part of the `register_new_terms_to_nbateam_taxonomy()` function works only for usual terms values ( 'name', 'slug', 'description' ) but not for extra fields I add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cases "wp_insert_term" does not save extra custom fields.

Please try with below code :

```
foreach ( $this->terms as $term_key=>$term) {
    // insert new terms in taxonomy
    wp_insert_term(
        $term['name'],
        $this->taxonomy,
        array(
            'slug'          => $term['slug'],
            'description'   => $term['description']
        )
    );

    update_option( 'term_team_code_' . $term['slug'], $term['code'] );
    update_option( 'term_team_nba_id_' . $term['slug'], $term['nba-id'] );
    update_option( 'term_team_espn_id_' . $term['slug'], $term['espn-id'] );
    update_option( 'term_team_color_' . $term['slug'], $term['color'] );

    unset( $term );
}
```

Comment: thx a lot, exactly what I was looking for !!